# My kafka error handler is not getting invoked, should I invoke explicitly?

Tags: error-handling, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am developing a kafka consumer API which consumes my messages from a topic. When it consumes an incorrect message (say not well formed JSON message), I am expecting my error handler should be called to notify the support group to take some action on the incorrect message.

But my error handler is not invoked automatically. Can you please advise what is missing in my code.

If I Autowire my error handler to my listener class and call explicitly, everything working fine.

Error Handler class

```
public class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler, KafkaListenerErrorHandler {
@Override
public Object handleError(Message<?> message, ListenerExecutionFailedException ex, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
.....
   }
}
```

Consumer config

```
@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaManualAckListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerGroupFactory());
    //factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
    //factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    //factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
    factory.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public MyErrorHandler myErrorHandler() {
    return new MyErrorHandler();
}
```

Listener class

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.proposal.topic.name}" ,                containerFactory = "kafkaManualAckListenerContainerFactory",                errorHandler ="${kafka.custom.error.handler}")
public void listen(ConsumerRecord<?,?> cr)  {   
     //Logic to get the message from topic and parse it to json, here i am testing with incorrect messages and producing JsonSyntaxException
}
```

Note: kafka.custom.error.handler = myErrorHandler in my property file.

I expect my error handler should get called automatically. But it is not. Am I missing any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If a deserialization error occurs, e.g. in the `JsonDeserializer`, it occurs before Spring gets the message, so we can't call the error handler.

Starting with version 2.2, you can use an [ErrorHandlingDeserializer2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer) to wrap the deserializer. This allows the framework to get the failed deserialization and pass it to the container's error handler.

> When a deserializer fails to deserialize a message, Spring has no way to handle the problem, because it occurs before the poll() returns. To solve this problem, version 2.2 introduced the ErrorHandlingDeserializer2. This deserializer delegates to a real deserializer (key or value). If the delegate fails to deserialize the record content, the ErrorHandlingDeserializer2 returns a null value and a DeserializationException in a header that contains the cause and the raw bytes. When you use a record-level MessageListener, if the ConsumerRecord contains a DeserializationException header for either the key or value, the container’s ErrorHandler is called with the failed ConsumerRecord. The record is not passed to the listener.

Comment: Thanks Gary, can you please suggest a case when my errorHandler will get called automatically. Assume I am not getting JsonDeserializer error.

Comment: If your listener throws an exception, the `KafkaListenerErrorHandler` method will be called by the listener adapter. If there is no listener error handler (or it, too, throws an exception), the `ErrorHandler` will be called by the container. The container doesn't know about the `KafkaListenerErrorHandler` - it's part of the listener as far as it is concerned.